# God works in mysterious ways

Tags: sources-mekorot

Does the proverb "God works in mysterious ways" or other similar variations, have any source or basis in the the Torah or other later rabbinic works ?

Comment: ממני יצאו כבושים

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A0_%D7%9B

Comment: כִּ֣י לֹ֤א מַחְשְׁבוֹתַי֙ מַחְשְׁב֣וֹתֵיכֶ֔ם וְלֹ֥א דַרְכֵיכֶ֖ם דְּרָכָ֑י נְאֻ֖ם יְהוָֽה׃

Answer (score 1):

That type of phraseology isn't explicit in the story with Yosef and the brothers but the following pesukim do contain that message: בראשית נ
(יט) וַיֹּאמֶר אֲלֵהֶם יוֹסֵף אַל תִּירָאוּ כִּי הֲתַחַת אֱלֹהִים אָנִי.
(כ) וְאַתֶּם חֲשַׁבְתֶּם עָלַי רָעָה אֱלֹהִים חֲשָׁבָהּ לְטֹבָה לְמַעַן עֲשֹׂה כַּיּוֹם הַזֶּה לְהַחֲיֹת עַם רָב.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous references to this idea in Tanach - albeit with different phraseology.

״רַבּ֣וֹת מַחֲשָׁב֣וֹת בְּלֶב־אִ֑ישׁ וַעֲצַ֥ת ה׳ הִ֣יא תָקֽוּם״ (Mishlei 19,21)

״כִּ֣י לֹ֤א מַחְשְׁבוֹתַי֙ מַחְשְׁב֣וֹתֵיכֶ֔ם וְלֹ֥א דַרְכֵיכֶ֖ם דְּרָכָ֑י נְאֻ֖ם ה׳.
כִּֽי־גָבְה֥וּ שָׁמַ֖יִם מֵאָ֑רֶץ כֵּ֣ן גָּבְה֤וּ
דְרָכַי֙ מִדַּרְכֵיכֶ֔ם וּמַחְשְׁבֹתַ֖י מִמַּחְשְׁבֹתֵיכֶֽם״

(Yeshayahu, 55,8-9)

״**הַחֵ֣קֶר אֱל֣וֹהַ תִּמְצָ֑א** אִ֤ם עַד־תַּכְלִ֖ית שַׁדַּ֣י תִּמְצָֽא״ (Iyov, 11,7)

״הֲל֨וֹא יָדַ֜עְתָּ אִם־לֹ֣א שָׁמַ֗עְתָּ אֱלֹהֵ֨י עוֹלָ֤ם ׀ יְהוָה֙ בּוֹרֵא֙ קְצ֣וֹת הָאָ֔רֶץ לֹ֥א יִיעַ֖ף וְלֹ֣א יִיגָ֑ע **אֵ֥ין חֵ֖קֶר לִתְבוּנָתֽוֹ**״ (Yeshayahu, 40,28)

If you read the commentaries there (Rashi, Ibn Ezra, Malbim, Radak etc.) as well as the midrashim you will find this idea explained further in reference to rewardand punishment, free will and G-d's for-knowledge, teshuva and sin etc.